# Action class not found - Struts 2.3

Tags: java, ant, struts2, weblogic

```
<Jul 29, 2015 10:55:58 AM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.st
ruts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
Unable to load configuration. - action - zip:C:/DEV/bea92MP3/user_projects/domains/cv_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL
_user/ficv2/3ie869/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/struts.xml:9:72
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:309)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Unable to load configuration. - action - zip:C:/DEV/bea92MP3/user_projects/domains/cv_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL
_user/ficv2/3ie869/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/struts.xml:9:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Action class [com.login.action.LoginAction] not found - action - zip:C:/DEV/bea92MP3/user_projects/domains/cv
_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/ficv2/3ie869/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/struts.xml:9:72
```

I get above exception on deploying ear built using struts 2.3 jars to weblogic server
                                                **struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login" class="com.login.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/jsp/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>ficv2.0</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Below is the list of jars used

- commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
- commons-io-2.2.jar
- commons-lang3-3.0.jar
- freemarker-2.3.22.jar
- javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
- ognl-3.0.6.jar
- struts2-core-2.3.24.jar
- xwork-core-2.3.24.jar

  **build.xml**

  ```
  <target name="set_env" unless="set_env" description="setup the properties.">

      <!-- All the system environment variables will be accessed by prefixing "env.". 
      To do that following property has to be set and be pointing to env -->

      <property environment="env" />
      <property name="java.home" value="${env.JAVA_HOME}" />

      <!-- Settings for global directories -->

      <property name="root.dir" value="." />
      <property name="source.dir" value="${root.dir}/src" />
      <property name="build.dir" value="${root.dir}/build" />
      <property name="webapp.dir" value="${root.dir}/WebContent" />
      <property name="lib.dir" value="${webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" />
      <property name="classes.dir" value="${webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" />

      <!-- Refers to cvs_build dir -->
      <property name="web.jar.name" value="struts2.0-web" />
      <property name="ear.name" value="struts2.0" />
      <property name="war.name" value="struts2.0" />

      <!-- Class path settings -->
      <property name="struts.jars" value="${lib.dir}/struts2-core-2.3.24.jar ; ${lib.dir}/freemarker-2.3.22.jar ; 
          ${lib.dir}/xwork-core-2.3.24.jar ; ${lib.dir}/ognl-3.0.6.jar ; ${lib.dir}/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar; 
          ${lib.dir}/commons-io-2.2.jar; ${lib.dir}/commons-lang3-3.0.jar;${lib.dir}/javaassist-3.11.0.GA.jar;" />
      <!-- End - Class path settings -->

  </target>

  <target name="init" depends="set_env" description="Initializes the required directories.">
      <mkdir dir="${webapp.dir}" />
      <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}" />
      <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
      <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
      <path id="project.class.path">
          <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
              <include name="*.jar" />
          </fileset>
      </path>
  </target>

  <target name="clean" depends="set_env" description="Cleans up the classes and output directories">
      <echo message="Deleting Classes..." />
      <delete dir="${classes.dir}" />
      <echo message="Deleting ear and war..." />
      <delete dir="${build.dir}/${ear.name}.ear" />
      <delete dir="${build.dir}/${war.name}.war" />
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compiles all source files">
      <javac debug="on" srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" verbose="true" classpath="${struts.jars}">
      </javac>
      <echo message="${webapp.dir}" />
      <copy file="${source.dir}/struts.xml" todir="${classes.dir}"/>  
  </target>

  <target name="create_jar" depends="compile" description="Package the Java classes into a jar.">
      <echo message="Creating Jar file..." />
      <delete file="${webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/${web.jar.name}.jar" />
      <jar jarfile="${webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/${web.jar.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/action/**" />
  </target>

  <target name="create_war">
      <delete file="${build.dir}/${war.name}.war" />
      <echo message="${webapp.dir}" />
      <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/${war.name}.war" update="yes" manifest="${webapp.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
          <fileset dir="${webapp.dir}">
              <include name="**" />
          </fileset>
          <zipfileset dir="${webapp.dir}/images" prefix="images">
              <include name="**" />
          </zipfileset>
      </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="create_ear" depends="create_war">
      <delete file="${build.dir}/${ear.name}.ear" />
      <ear earfile="${build.dir}/${ear.name}.ear" appxml="${root.dir}/META-INF/application.xml">
          <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
              <include name="*.jar" />
          </fileset>
          <fileset file="${build.dir}/${war.name}.war" />
      </ear>
  </target>

  <target name="all" depends="set_env, create_jar, create_ear" description="Perform all targets." />
  ```

**Please let me know how can this be solved.**

Comment: problem of conflicting library jars.

Comment: May I know which jars are conflicting or which jars have to be used.

Comment: Means may be you are placing same jar(s) in some other location.

Comment: How to identify the jar and location. Please help

Comment: where are you placing your ear ? can you confirm that the ear contains your struts.xml in the right location ?

Comment: ear is placed in build directory. I can confirm struts.xml is placed in WEB-INF/classes directory

Comment: should I place struts.xml in lib folder?

Comment: how does struts.xml look for action classes? Will it search in classes directory or lib directory?

Comment: It will search classes on the classpath.

Comment: Has it got to do anything with web logic server. I am using weblogic server 9.2? Because if I deploy the project(not war) on tomcat server, it works.

Comment: > Action class [com.ssga.fi.cv.login.action.LoginAction] not found - action - zip:C:/DEV/bea92MP3/user_projects/domains/cv
_domain/**servers/AdminServer**/tmp/_WL_user/ficv2/3ie869/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/struts.xml:9:72 Luckily I barely remember the days of BEA WebLogic 9.2, but... are you sure you are deploying to the right server ? AdminServer ?! Isn't that the server for the administration console, shouldn't you deploy on an operative node instead ?

Comment: @Karthik Do you deploy ear on Tomcat? And it works?!

Comment: I didnt deploy ear. I just deployed the project on tomcat and it works

Comment: What is _wl_cls_gen.jar as specified in the stack trace?

Comment: Dude. You are doing it wrong. By it, I mean everything. Stop reinventing the wheel squared and do the things right. The easy way, the standard way, the way the other people do. Don't deploy on admin servers, if you have an ear then deploy an ear, because it's totally unclear *what* you are doing, the only thing clear is that *it is wrong*. People will stop trying to help on your problems very soon, because your problems are unsolvable, because they're methodology-related, not software related, and you'll be alone with your wrong methodologies. Start doing it right, right now. Good luck.

Comment: My war structure                                                                                                       ficv2.0
   |
 images
 jsp
 META-INF
 WEB-INF
   |
  web.xml
  weblogic.xml
  lib
  classes
    |
  struts.xml
  com...

Comment: Please post the directory structure of a struts2 war. I guess I am getting error because of not properly packaging my project

Comment: Download an existing project, or run an archetype with maven to generate an empty project, and then compare its structure with your

Comment: Finally, I resolved it. I was having issues because of the build script. I changed the build script. Thanks all for your posts.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the build script which resolved the error **though do not know what was wrong with previous build script(may be previous build script was causing jars conflict).**

```
<project name="Struts2.0" default="archive" basedir=".">

    <description>
           Basic Struts 2 Java Web Application
    </description>

    <property file="build.properties"/>



    <!-- ==================== Clean Target ==================================== -->

    <!--
      The "clean" target deletes any previous "build" and "dist" directory,
      so that you can be ensured the application can be built from scratch.
    -->
    <target name="clean" description="Delete old build and dist directories">
        <delete dir="${dist.home}"/>
        <delete dir="${build.home}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- ==================== Init Target ================================== -->

    <!--

      The "init" target is used to create the "build" destination directory,
      Normally, this task is executed indirectly when needed.

    -->
    <target name="init" depends="clean"  description="Create build directory">

        <mkdir dir="${build.home}" />

    </target>

    <!-- ==================== Compile Target ================================== -->

    <!--

      The "compile" target transforms source files (from your "src" directory)
      into class files in the appropriate location in the build directory.
      This example assumes that you will be including your classes in an
      unpacked directory hierarchy under "/WEB-INF/classes".

    -->
    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile Java sources">


        <mkdir dir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes" />

        <javac srcdir="${source.home}"
                destdir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes"
                debug="${compile.debug}"
                deprecation="${compile.deprecation}"
                optimize="${compile.optimize}"
                source="1.5" target="1.5">

            <classpath>
                <path>
                    <fileset dir="${lib.home}" />
                </path>
            </classpath>

        </javac>

    </target>

    <!-- ==================== Build Target ================================== -->

    <!--

      The "build" target copies all non class files to build directory

    -->

    <target name="build" depends="compile" description="Copies all non Java classes to build directoy">
        <copy todir="${build.home}">
            <fileset dir="${webapp.home}" excludes="CVS,**/*.class" />
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes">
            <fileset dir="${source.home}" excludes="CVS,**/*.java" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- ==================== Archive Target ================================== -->

    <!--

      The "archive" target create a binary archive of all files in build.home

    -->

    <target name="archive" depends="build" description="Create binary archive of all files in dist.home">

        <mkdir     dir="${dist.home}" />

        <!-- Create application WAR file -->
        <jar jarfile="${dist.home}/${app.name}.war"
                basedir="${build.home}" />

    </target>   

</project>
```

Answer (score -2):

struts.xml must be placed in WEB-INF directory. And also please make sure  "LoginAction" is present in the specified path (com\ssga\fi\cv\login\action\LoginAction)

Comment: Since it is struts 2.0. struts.xml must be class path so I have placed it in src folder. But after compile target, its gets copied to WEB-INF/classes directory. Also LoginAction is present in com\ssga\fi\cv\login\action\LoginAction

Comment: Has it got to do anything with web logic server. I am using weblogic server 9.2?Because if I deploy the project(not war) on tomcat server, it works.

Comment: <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> , here constant tag is not is not closed.But i dont thk this is a problem. There is a duplicate struts.xml file in ur workspace.  Remove Struts-related libraries from the servlet container; deploy them, it should work.

Comment: May I know from which folder of web logic should I remove struts-related libraries

Comment: @DivyaS The `<constant>` tag *is* closed; that's what the `/>` does. Also, `struts.xml` by default needs to be at the root of the classpath.

Comment: Does not hold true for Struts 2.0